# lint error Useless assignment to variable

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, if-statement

I have this if condition in model

```
  if column_value = 'Y'
    Abc.new('test', latest.column_1, latest.column_2, latest.column_3)
  else
    Abc.new('test2', latest.column_1, latest.column_2, latest.column_3)
  end
end
```

column_value is not a variable. I am using column value thats present in active record.
why i am getting the lint error `Useless assignment to variable - column`

EDIT:
tried column_value == 'Y' but then get error `undefined variable or method column_value`
also tried self.column_value got lint error `redundant self detected`

Comment: `=` is assignment and since `'Y'` is true the if block will always run and the else block will never run. `==` is a comparison operator and will be conditional. basically you are stating `if true # do something` rather than `if something == true #do something`

Comment: tried column == 'Y' but then get error undefined local variable or method column. weird that when i have = it runs successfully but lint throws error

Comment: You can use `column_value = 'Y'`, but, as said, your `else` will never run. And, even if you do use that logic it'll be very confusing to anyone else who has to maintain the code later, so don't do that. You didn't give us enough information to solve the problem. Read "[mcve]".

Comment: Are you sure you have a method for retrieving "column_value" since your code is so ambiguous it is nearly impossible for use to help from here. Also not all linting can save you try writing rspecs specs with RuboCop on (apparently my blocks are too long :) ). **Based on your comment below this example is not true because you did not explain that this was at a class level or the answer would have been (you cannot do this *and you are using assignment*)**

Comment: fixed it. please check my answer below. Apologies for not giving all details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed with ternary operator and needed latest.column_value

```
Abc.new(latest.column_value == 'Y' ? 'test' : 'test2', latest.column_1, latest.column_2, latest.column_3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `==` operator instead of `=` assignment operator in `if` clause:

```
if self.column_name == 'Y'
# do this
else
# do that
end
```

Comment: tried but then get error undefined local variable or method column. weird that when i have = it runs successfully but lint throws error

Comment: try self.column_name instead of column

Comment: tried that. lint error redundant self detected. if condition is inside a class method (self.class_method)

Comment: @User7354632781 you cannot access a column value from the context of a class just as you cannot access a room from the roof of a building. You must be inside the building to access the room and you must be inside an instance to access a column value